# In Azure Webjob When using CustomQueueProcessorFactory messages returns to queue even after DeleteMessageAsync is called

Tags: azure, overriding, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

I have tried implementing my own **QueueProcessorFactory**, and it works fine, besides one thing I can’t wrap my head around. After I have tried a message for 5 times (default) it runs *CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync* and then *DeleteMessageAsync*.

So far so good, but 10 minutes later the message appears in the queue again with a dequeue count 5, and it is in the poison queue too, and then the same procedure, *CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync*, *DeleteMessageAsync*, an extra item in posionqueue exactly the same as the one already copied and 10 min later the same procedure but with a dequeue count 6. Should I change the ExpirationTime and set it to now when deleting, or do I miss something else?

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        config.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public List<CustomQueueProcessor> CustomQueueProcessors = new List<CustomQueueProcessor>();
    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        CustomQueueProcessor processor = new CustomQueueProcessor(context);
        CustomQueueProcessors.Add(processor);
        return processor;
    }

    public class CustomQueueProcessor : QueueProcessor
    {
        public CustomQueueProcessor(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
        public override Task<bool> BeginProcessingMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.BeginProcessingMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
        }
        public override Task CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, FunctionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(message, result, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override Task CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, CloudQueue poisonQueue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(message, poisonQueue, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override Task DeleteMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.DeleteMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task ReleaseMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, FunctionResult result, TimeSpan visibilityTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            visibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            await base.ReleaseMessageAsync(message, result, visibilityTimeout, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

if I add some ConsoleWritelines i get this output:

Start omitted because of repetition
.
.
.

BeginProcessingMessageAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 5 Date: 2017-06-26 13:33:42
Executing 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Reason='New queue message detected on '01testqueue'.', Id=17405a55-6d28-48b2-a874-718c0b741f61)
Test QueueProcessorFactory
Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> System.Exception: Derp!
   at WebJobTest1.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage(String message, TextWriter log)

...message omitted....

CompleteProcessingMessageAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 5
CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 5
Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue '01testqueue-poison'.
CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync message: da643007-954a-4296-9e9a-54ebb0aec6c5 dequeue count: 5
Ten minute waiting time:
BeginProcessingMessageAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 6 Date: 2017-06-26 13:43:46
Executing 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage' (Reason='New queue message detected on '01testqueue'.', Id=c22fe457-cb70-4cc8-a8a4-550cd44a8345)
Test QueueProcessorFactory
Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
CompleteProcessingMessageAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 6
CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync message: d3c88182-ff39-4f81-8c29-b4ce0b2062ad dequeue count: 6
Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue '01testqueue-poison'.
CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync message: c43fd9fb-c2d7-4745-91ae-33cdc407ede6 dequeue count: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that it dues to the known issue when using Storage SDK 8.x with WebJobs SDK. Here are the similar issues:

- [Poison messages stay undeleted-but-invisible with the latest WindowsAzure.Storage 8.1.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1107)
- [WebJobs V1.1.2 fails to remove poison messages from queue with V8.0.1 of Storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/985)

Per my test, this issue has not been fixed for now. You could downgrade the Storage SDK or change `CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync` as follows:

```html
protected override Task CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(CloudQueueMessage message, CloudQueue poisonQueue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var newMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(message.Id, message.PopReceipt);
    newMessage.SetMessageContent(message.AsBytes);
    return base.CopyMessageToPoisonQueueAsync(newMessage, poisonQueue, cancellationToken);
}
```